# How to get hp printer to select correct trays on samba shared printer

Tags: printing, samba, hp

My first post here.

Clean install of 12.04.1. Previously 10.04. Have been running a p2035n printer without problem.

Now, no matter what paper tray I select it prints to the top "by-pass" feeder--not the lower main tray. And when I select to print to manual feed, it does not wait for me to put in paper (like it used to), but prints immediately.

The printer is on a samba share and is physically plugged into a WinXP machine. Its uri is smb:///computername/p2035n.

I have tried several of the offered drivers for this hp machine, and even tried generic-laser. Same result on all.

Here are some other things I have tried (losing 2-3 hours of my time!):

hp-check -t reports “error: User needs to be member of group 'lp' to enable print, scan & fax. ” and “warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend to function in HPLIP.”

needed to download HPLIP 3.12.11

followed http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html

sh hplip-3.12.11-run

says that before setup logout and then on login run hp-setup

hp-setup could not find the printer

ran hp-check -t again, found I was not in group lp

ran hp-check --fix and it fixed that problem, asks for reboot

rebooted after running update manager (new kernel) and hp-check -t shows no errors this time

all the tray selections end up on the bypass tray

hp-setup still cannot find the printer

So is there a way to make this work?

Thanks!

:- Doug.

Comment: try using `localhost:631` in your browser and setting it using the administrator tab

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening a terminal and issue this command `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` This package contains utilities with graphical user interface (GUI) for
 HPLIP: HP Toolbox, HP Fax etc.

Comment: Rick Green-- Thanks for your response. This gui reports No installed hp devices found. I tried the cups web interface and the printer shows up, but I do not see anything I can do to modify it. The gui says only devices installed with the hp: or hpfax: cups backend will appear in the manager. Not sure what to do for that.